# Angular Material Data Table Sorting not doing anything

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular mat table that correctly displays data. I am attempting to add sorting functionality with mat-sort. Right now, the little arrows appear beside each column but the table doesn't respond at all when they are clicked. Many other SO problems with similar issues were solved by taking the table outside of an `*ngIf` or setting the `datasource` later in the lifecycle. I don't think my code has those problems although I could be wrong.

*table.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';

import { Data } from '...';

@Component({
    ...
})

export class WorkflowManagerTableComponent{

    @Input() data: Data[];
    @Input() title: string;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['select'];
    dataProps: string[] = [];

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log("ngOnChanges")
        this.data = changes.data.currentValue;
        if (this.data) {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
            this.dataArray = this.data;
            for (var property in this.data[0]){
                if(this.data[0].hasOwnProperty(property)){
                    this.dataProps.push(property)
                }
            }
            this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns.concat(this.dataProps);
        }
    }

    public dataArray: Data[];
    public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Data>;1
}
```

*table.component.html*

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataArray" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let prop of dataProps" matColumnDef="{{prop}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> 
            {{prop}}
         </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{data[prop]}} </td>
     </ng-container>
</table>
```

How can I get mat sort to work? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to follow with code example you have provided. first of all you don't have to assign the change `currentValue` to input property it would be set for you.

If you are trying to sort in material data table so I am expecting to see sorting function in the component. Angular won't sort things for you. This sorting function would be called in the subscription function for the matSort viewChiled property after you call `sortChange`. Would be something like this:

```
this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => {
   // sorting implantation goes here; 
});
```

You could find clear examples in the [documentatiion](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples).

One more thing you should unsubscribe for each subscription you have in the component when you are done with it. I hope that's answer your question.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding any use of a subscription in the doc you provided, what section is it in?

Comment: It is asking the server to do the actual sorting cause that what happens most of the time cause you don't have the whole data.

Answer (score 0):

You should have  and  tags in the last section of the table. 
For example: 
  `...
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>`

This defines the header-rows and rows for content. If you don't have this, it cannot recognise the  as headers, then of course sort is not going to work even if you have mat-sort-header in it.
Have a look at the first example on angular material website for table.https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: I already have those tags in my code, I didn't include them in this post because I didnt think they were relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import MatSortModule

```
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
```

See `material-module` at https://stackblitz.com/angular/oolrmmvqyjd?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
```